# Div scrolling ability lost depending on viewport size

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, viewport

I have a document embedded on a page that can only be scrolled when the viewport is 480px or less. I can't for the life of me find the rule which is causing this behavior.

here's the document. https://onarbor.com/work/451.

Removing the `position:absolute` on `.crocodoc-viewport` when the viewport is 480px or less can eliminate the scrolling, but that attribute is set the same way when the viewport is greater than 480px so that is not the issue.

Does anyone know how to find all the media-queries that apply to a page? Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question. The following is the rule that needs to **not** be restricted to 480px. If you take this rule outside the media query then the scrolling is restored:

This:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

  .DocViewerDiv.height0{
    height:0px;
  }
}
```

Should be this:

```
.DocViewerDiv.height0{
   height:0px;
}
```